# Was Jesus a Hindu saint and belong to the religion of Hinduism?

Tags: life-of-jesus, history, hinduism

I am from  India and in various newspapers and in different electronic medias, **people are arguing that Jesus was a Hindu person. His religion was Hinduism**. He was born in Kerala state of country India in a Brahman family.

Also,in one of  stack exchange sites, it is said that [Jesus was an incarnate of Hindu God "Shiva"](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/is-jesus-an-avatar-of-lord-vishnu)

So my simple question is that are these true stories or just  rumors?

Comment: Can you provide links to these Indian news and media sources?

Answer (score 11):

It's quite possible that someone with a similar name was born in India at around that time, but this person is not Jesus as understood by Christianity.  Our understanding of the details of his life comes from the Gospels, the first four books of the New Testament, which make it clear that he was [born in Bethlehem,](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+2%3A1-7&version=KJV) a small village near the city of Jerusalem in Israel, to [an observing Jewish family](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%202%3A21-24&version=KJV), who [raised him as a Jew,](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%202%3A40-52&version=KJV) and that he lived in the Roman-occupied lands of Palestine for the majority of his life.  It gives no indication that he ever headed east across Arabia, much less came anywhere near the Indian subcontinent, although he did [send his disciples "into all the world"](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2016%3A15&version=KJV)--which necessarily includes India--to preach the Gospel.

Simply put, any person not matching this description is a different person than the Jesus of Christianity.

Answer (score 0):

> Was Jesus a Hindu saint?

If you are Muslim you believe Jesus was only a prophet. If you are Jew "Jesus was been just one the most influent false prophet". If you are atheist Jesus was only a good man. If you are Hindu, why Jesus can't be an Hindu saint?

You can be Christian or not but is undeniable that the figure of Jesus has influenced the whole of humanity. So every one see is figure giving a proper interpretation.

> [Thomas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_the_Apostle) is traditionally believed to have sailed to India in AD 52 to
>   spread the Christian faith, and is believed to have landed at the port
>   of Muziris, Tamilakam (modern-day North Paravur and Kodungalloor in
>   modern-day Kerala state) where there was a Jewish community at the
>   time.

So is possible that with the passage of time differente culture and tradition was mixed.

> Jesus was a Hindu person. His religion was Hinduism

As far as I know there are no historical documents that affirm this (that Jesus was from India). So in my opinion, when first Christians went to predicate in India the naive population reinterpreted is figure.

Comment: The gospels are historical documents, and they make it pretty clear that Jesus was a Jew, not Hindu.

Comment: I don't understand why downvotes... I gave an hypothesis on why there is some belief that Jesus was from India.  I didn't say He was from India. "The gospels are historical documents" this is not true. I'm a credent so I belief that what is written is the truth. But you can't assure that these things are true. A greek men 3000 years ago believed that the "Iliad" was the truth about the Trojan War. So isn't correct in my opinion critique who did a rational discourse!

Comment: I have been living in India for the last 53 years. I have never heard anyone argue, nor any media quoting such an argument by a person of integrity, that Jesus was a Hindu .

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan me too.. Never heard. But someone tells. He was asking if these voices were true. And I gave my opinion on the causes of this rumors. Apparently , though, some bigots were offended and downvote.